# Extra space in Tkinter while Changing Frames

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying for make GUI for python where Frames are replaceable on button click ,I tried following many tutorials for getting it done, but could do it , so after mixing something from here and there I tried something and seems to be working, but Whenever frame changes Extra space is added at bottom , I tried everything but couldn't get it done.

Here is my Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.master.title("Main Window")

        for r in range(6):
            self.master.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)    
        for c in range(5):
            self.master.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
            Button(master, text="Button {0}".format(c)).grid(row=6,column=c,sticky=E+W)

        Frame1 = Frame(master, bg="#000000")
        Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 10, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S) 

        Button(Frame1, text='Email \n Checker', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 22, 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=10, y=55)

        Button(Frame1, text='Auto Email\nSender', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 20, 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=10, y=215)

        Button(Frame1, text='Auto DM\n Sender', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 22, 'normal'),
                 command=lambda: self.switch_frame(StartPage)).place(x=17, y=366)

        Frame3 = Frame(master, bg="green")
        Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 60, columnspan = 30, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    
    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class()
        new_frame.tkraise()

def btnClickFunction():
    print('clicked')

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        # self.master.title("Main Window")

        Frame1 = Frame(master, bg="#000000")
        Frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 10, columnspan = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S) 

        Button(root, text='Email', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 22, 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=10, y=55)

        Button(Frame1, text='Auto Email\nSender', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 20, 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=10, y=215)

        Button(root, text='Auto DM\n Sender', bg='#FFFFFF', font=('arial', 22, 'normal'),
                 command=lambda: self.switch_frame(Application)).place(x=17, y=366)

        Frame3 = Frame(master, bg="green")
        Frame3.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 60, columnspan = 30, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        # Frame3.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="x")


    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class()
        # frame = new_frame
        new_frame.tkraise()
        

root = Tk()
root.geometry("871x560")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Whenever I click **Auto DM Sender** it changes button **Email Checker** to **Email**, but It adds blank space at bottom of window

[image: blank space at buttom]

What I exactly want to do is When I click Either of button the Content in Green part Should Change respectively. I can develop what content to show in the Green part But I'm not able to develop how to change that green part on button click, If someone could help with a demo on button click on how to change the green part it would be really helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about we just start completely over? There are a lot of mistakes and confusion. It would be easier to just start fresh. You will need to customize my example to fit your app, but it gives you a working foundation to build on.

List of Biggest Problems:

1. you are using `grid_(row/column)configure()` improperly
2. you are mostly building the same thing twice
3. it's frame-alicious. You can use Tk as the main frame

**example foundation**

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self,  *args, **kwargs)
        
        #use this as the master for your buttons
        sidebar = Frame(self, bg="#0000FF")
        sidebar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")
        
        #button example        
        btn  = Button(sidebar, text='switch', font=('arial', 20, 'normal'), command=self.switch)
        btn.place(x=10, y=55)
        
        #use this frame as the master for main content
        self.main1 = Frame(self, bg="#00FF00")
        self.main1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")
        
        
        #use this frame as master for alternate content
        #note that this is "waiting" to be added to the grid
        self.main2 = Frame(self, bg="#FF0000")
        

        #config layout ~ notice this is AFTER everything has been added to the grid
        #also note that the first argument is the element to configure, not a number
        self.grid_columnconfigure(sidebar, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(sidebar, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(self.main1, weight=6)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(self.main1, weight=1)
        
        #frames to toggle between
        self.frames = [self.main1, self.main2]
    
    #this is just an example of removing and adding element to/from the grid
    #you will need to change this to suit your needs by applying ...
    #grid_remove() to the current main frame and grid() to the new main frame     
    def switch(self, **kwargs):
        self.frames[0].grid_remove()
        self.frames.append(self.frames.pop(0)) #cheating and dirty rotation
        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nswe")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.geometry("871x560")
    app.title('Frame Switch Example')
    app.mainloop()
```